# String.Insert causing Invalid Qualifier error?

Tags: vba

I am trying to take the value of a text box on a user form and assign it to a string variable, then insert hyphens into that string variable using the String class's Insert method. Every time I run this code, I get an error 'Invalid Qualifier" with AcctUnitString highlighted.

```
Dim AcctUnitString As String

AcctUnitString = AcctUnit.Text
AcctUnitString = AcctUnitString.Insert(2, "-")

Debug.Print (AcctUnitString)
```

AcctUnit is the name of the text field on the user form. Any ideas what might be causing this error, or a better way of doing what I'm trying to do?

The user will enter a 13 digit code in the text box (example 9200030015001) and I want to format it thusly: 92-0003-001-5001. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: In the example I gave above if I were to enter 9200030015001 in the textbox and just `Debug.Print(AcctUnit.Text)` the value is 9200030015001.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of a built in Excel function to do what you are looking for.

```
Sub test()

    Dim AcctUnitString As String

    AcctUnitString = "9200030015001"
    AcctUnitString = InsertString(AcctUnitString, "-", 2)
    MsgBox AcctUnitString
End Sub

Private Function InsertString(OriginalString As String, StringToInsert As String, WhereToInsertIt As Integer) As String
    Dim String1 As String, String2 As String
    String1 = Mid(OriginalString, 1, WhereToInsertIt)
    String2 = Mid(OriginalString, WhereToInsertIt + 1, Len(OriginalString))
    InsertString = String1 & StringToInsert & String2
End Function
```

http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?141943-Insert-string-within-another-string-at-specific-position

Comment: This gives me 92-0030015001, which is a bit closer than an error for sure, but it's replacing one of the characters in the original string with a "-" rather than inserting between the existing characters.

Comment: You are right. I didn't notice that given the zeroes - I've added a user function which can do this.

Answer (score 4):

From  [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/pl/exceldev/thread/604c8a6b-dc05-4db8-935d-09dd77221a5b)

> Strings are not objects in VBA, hence they have no methods such as Substring or Remove, as in VB.Net.

Comment: Well, that certain explains a lot, but are there functions in VBA that can do string handling?

Comment: There appears to be standalone functions with similar names for processing streams. I had run into a similar problem, with string.Trim(), but VBA's version is Trim(string). Maybe standalone functions exist for your problem as well.